# how to i take added data's id? (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

*(My First language is not English)*
i'm inserting new data to mysql but i want to take added data's id in same page.

for example: (im using auto increment)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO example (name) VALUES ('$name')";
$query = mysql_query($sql,connectDB());

if ($query)
{
   return /*added data id*/;
}
```

How i do?

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to return the most recently created id.

```
if ($query)
{
   echo mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Comment: but be careful on concurent connections and inserts. could happen that mysql_insert_id to not be the one you just added.